# How to update the values in the same component on making multiple selections in Angular using mat-select?

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding, angular-material, angular-material2

I am making a pizza ordering app, and I have a MenuComponent, which lists all the menu items provided by the restaurant.

Now this items are shown as individual cards with all the information. Also I'm providing an option to customize the item with multiple toppings.

Now problem here is I'm displaying the base price of the item, as soon as user makes the selection for extra topping, I want to update the base price with the addition of the extra costs.

Here is how my menu.component.html looks like:

```
    <div fxFlex *ngFor="let category of categories">
        <h3>{{category.name}}</h3>
            <div *ngFor="let item of items">
                <mat-card *ngIf="item.category == category.name" class="itemcard">

                    <mat-card-header>

                        <mat-card-title>{{item.name}}</mat-card-title>
                        <mat-card-subtitle>{{item.category}}</mat-card-subtitle>
                        <span class="flex-spacer"></span>
                        <div>$ {{item.price_large}}</div>
                    </mat-card-header>
                    <mat-card-content>
                        <mat-form-field>
                            <mat-label>Extra Toppings</mat-label>
                            <mat-select multiple>
                                <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppings" [value]="topping.rate">{{topping.name}}</mat-option>
                            </mat-select>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </mat-card-content>
                    <span class="flex-spacer"></span>

                    <button mat-button color="primary"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add to Cart</button>
                </mat-card>

            </div>
    </div>
```

the **div** tag is where i'm displaying the base price, and also the same place i want to update it, when extra toppings are chosen. I read somewhere to use the 2 way binding approach, but right now I'm not getting any kick on thoughts and stuck and don't know how to proceed further.

And also how to only reflect the changes for that particular item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new component, representing a menu item, let's call it MenuItemComponent.
Pass 'item' and 'category' as variables to this component using parent-child relation (this might help https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction) and add a variable representing the chosen toping price. Add an event handler to the select, so it will update this variable.
So our new component will look like:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-menu-item',
    templateUrl: './menuitem.component.html'
  })
  export class MenuItemComponent {
    @Input() item;
    @Input() category;
    private chosenToppingPrice = 0;

    constructor(){}

    onToppingSelect(event){
      this.chosenToppingPrice = event.target.value;
    }
  }
```

And it's HTML will look like:

```html
<mat-card *ngIf="item.category == category.name" class="itemcard">
    <mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-title>{{item.name}}</mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-subtitle>{{item.category}}</mat-card-subtitle>
        <span class="flex-spacer"></span>
        <div>$ {{item.price_large + chosenToppingPrice}}</div>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content>
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Extra Toppings</mat-label>
            <mat-select multiple>
                <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppings" [value]="topping.rate" (change)="onToppingSelect($event)">{{topping.name}}</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
    </mat-card-content>
    <span class="flex-spacer"></span>
    <button mat-button color="primary"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add to Cart</button>
</mat-card>
```

And finally, menu.component.html will look like:

```html
<div fxFlex *ngFor="let category of categories">
    <h3>{{category.name}}</h3>
    <div *ngFor="let item of items">
        <app-menu-item [item]="item" [category]="category"></app-menu-item>
    </div>
</div>
```

This might be a bit long but this way you can manipulate each card data individually.

In addition, instead of using `*ngIf="item.category == category.name"`, you could simply use the map function.

Comment: Okay, I'll definitely try this approach, but I was thinking that do I really need to create a brand new component, just for using that small div element to update the price.... And also is there any standard guideline on when to actually create a new component in angular?

Comment: You can always find a workaround I guess, but this isn't really a big change if you think about it, and it is the proper way to do it in my opinion. You can read this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46192426/how-to-tell-when-to-create-a-new-component regarding when to create a new component.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked and made my concepts for parent-child interaction a little better. Thanks for the followup link as well.